# Get Gmail User Profile Picture and Name with Google API client

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

The [Google API client](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/PeopleV1.html) has [Class: Google::Apis::PeopleV1::Name](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/PeopleV1/Name.html) and [Google::Apis::PeopleV1::Photo](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/PeopleV1/Photo.html) how do I hit these endpoints? I tried

```
p = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::Photo.new
response = p.url
```

But it returns `nil`. Opposed to this [GmailService](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService.html) has instance methods like `get_user_message` which I can call like this

```
@service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
# authorization is done
response = @service.get_user_message(user_id, message_id)
```

It returns a `response` object which has the `message`, now I want to fetch the User's name and Photo, but I did not find any method to access this information. How do I retrieve the User's name and photo using the API client?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I'm fetching Emails using Google API ruby client. What I want to achieve is to get the names and avatars of the users sending and receiving emails in my inbox. I only have their email addresses, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the value retrieved with the method of users.messages.get in Gmail API doesn't include "User Profile Picture". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) So for example, in order to retrieve the URL of user's profile photo, how about using the method of people.connections.list in People API? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
service = Google::Apis::PeopleV1::PeopleServiceService.new
service.authorization = authorize
response = service.list_person_connections(
    'people/me',
    'page_size': 1000,
    'person_fields': "names,emailAddresses,photos"
)
puts "No connections" if response.connections.empty?
result = response.connections.map {|person| {
    'resourceName': person.resource_name,
    'email': person.email_addresses[0].value,
    'photos': person.photos.map {|e| e.url}
}}
puts result
```

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following result is returned.

```
[
  {"resourceName": "people/###", "email": "###", "photos": ["https://###"]},
  {"resourceName": "people/###", "email": "###", "photos": ["https://###", "https://###"]},
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

- The URLs of `phtots` are the URLs of the user's photo images.

#### Note:

- In this case, it seems that the method of otherContacts.list doesn't return the user's photo data.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list)

Comment: The people.connections.list method says that it "Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts." I do not have those people in my contacts, they've emails sent/received in my Gmail account. Does that count as being in my contacts?

Comment: @Prime Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, it is required to use "otherContacts" in people API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts) But unfortunately, it seems that the method of otherContacts.list doesn't return the user's photo data as mentioned above. And in this case, such photp cannot be also retrieved by Gmail API. I apologize for this.